# Richfaces4 skin does not get reflected

Tags: richfaces

I am setting the skin value in Richaces 4 with some other value for example "blueSky" in the below snippet, but this does not reflect in the application? Its there anything I am missing?

I also restarted the server and my server is Tomcat 6.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct name is 'org.richfaces.skin'. Check [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-8968)

Try the following corrected code

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
  <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>
```